# Using Product Key like ID Instead of using ID [ Primary Key]

Tags: mysql

[Please Excuse My Grammar]

Right now I'm planning to change my Search Data Form. Instead of using ID [Primary Key] as the Referrence ID. I want to make a Product Key / CD Key. Reference ID. Ive heard it is consistent to use a Foreign Key. anyway is it possible to do that?

```
CREATE TABLE test ( 
    id INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
    referrenceid INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    CONSTRAINT FK_test_visitors 
    FOREIGN KEY (referrenceid) 
        REFERENCES visitors (id) 
);
```

p.s 
im kinda newbie.

Comment: Can you include a sample of what the database table structure is, and what the data looks like? As text please, not an image or screenshot.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `referrenceid` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_test_visitors` FOREIGN KEY (`referrenceid`) REFERENCES `visitors` (`id`)


im not sure if this is what you are looking for :o